# Display real content not content wrapped by HTML tags and inline CSS

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, symfony, twig

My database contains contents that are wrapped with HTML tags and contain inline CSS styles.

The problem is these contents are displayed like they are in database. My goal is to be able to display the real content after execution of HTML and CSS.

I am using MySQL Database and Symfony PHP framework.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How about [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags)?

Comment: Paste a piece of data here

Comment: @hallaji. Thank you for ur feedback, what data? HTML data? or the code I am using to retreieve data from database??

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I mean to explain more. How your data is stored and how do you want to diplay? by code samples. So people can realize it better...

Comment: @AmalMurali. Thank you for your time. I think  `strip_tags()` will will remove the tags and styles, no? I need the final text to keep the style (to be executed)

Comment: So.... View it in a browser, they interpret and display HTML pretty well

Comment: @JAL, I dont understand you well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use Twig, in that case you need the [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter, like:

```
{{ dataFromDatabase|raw }}
```

Comment: Perfect help, Thanks many times, also for being smart and understanding that I am looking for a solution in Twig layer. Have a nice day.